# Image URI not displaying the image in C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on a project to develop a UWP app using C#. I've used the following code to assign an image to the page.

```
CarImageDisplay.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(param[7]));
```

Here the value of `param[7]` is set as:

```
string imgpath = @"C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JijoyProjectv2\JijoyProjectv2\Assets\Maruti-Alto.jpg";
```

The app returns no runtime error but the image is not displayed on the page. Please suggest something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UWP app lives inside a "sandbox", so it's not possible for it to directly to point to file located in your computer.

Here's a good guide on MSDN which shows how to load resources: [How to load file resources (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322.aspx)

If the image lives inside your app package, you should be able to point to it using ms-appx: scheme. For example:

```
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Maruti-Alto.jpg");
```